# Rendering dynamic table displays cell contents in wrong order

Tags: arrays, vue.js, html-table, vuejs3

I'm trying to render a table with dynamic headers, and populating it with an array of objects, the goal is to align the cells filled with the object properties in the same column as the header.

The header is an array of strings, and each string corresponds to an object property, such that the value of the string is equal to the object property.

Each object does not necessarily contain the table header as a property. Here's what I've got so far:

```
       <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th
                v-for="header in activeTableHeaders"
                :key="header"
                scope="col"
              >
                <p>
                  {{ header }}
                </p>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(dataItem, outerIndex) in renderableResults" :key="outerIndex">
              <td v-for="(key, innerIndex) in activeTableHeaders" :key="innerIndex">
                {{ dataItem[key] }}
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Here's a poorly cropped image of what's displayed:
[image]

Here's what goes wrong: When I filter the data, e.g:
`renderableResults.value = renderableResults.value.filter(doc => doc['ledv'] >= 200);` and then log the results, I can see that the results have correctly had all results with the property of 'ledv' less than 200 been filtered out.

Yet, the table columns still contain values less than 200:
[image: Image2]

I'm handling a lot of results so it was hard for me to track down where the incorrect values are coming from, I managed to find in the first row, the value of '190' is coming from `lsv` not `ledv`.

Any idea what's going wrong? I can't seem to figure it out myself and I'm truly stuck.

Here's what `activeTableHeaders` looks like: [image: Image3]

Here's the first result from [`renderableResults`](https://pastebin.com/D0DYKL3c) although it appears that the first result in `renderableResults` isn't the first result to be rendered, strange.

Thank you in advance! Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Because Firebase doesn't offer programmatic creation of indexes which means I cannot filter on the backend, the filtering occurs on the frontend:
When the component is initialised, it fetches all documents from Firebase, then it watches for filters that the user can add. The code won't fit in this comments so I've put the appropriate snippets in a pastebin:
https://pastebin.com/9McDgwC4
The WIP project can be used here: https://advwebdevproject-7d239.web.app/#/Query/

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that although I was filtering the results correctly, the results that are rendered are also paginated, I forgot to update the paginated results